# Row operations in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, mean

Im trying to perform a simple sum and mean by rows using [data.table](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/), but I am getting unexpected results. I followed the help in section 2 of the [FAQ manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.pdf) for data.table. I found a way that works, but I am not sure why this method in section 2 of the FAQ is not.
This method gives me the incorrect result (i.e., it is giving me the value of the first column):

```
dt[, genesum:=lapply(.SD,sum), by=gene]
head(dt)

      gene      TCGA_04_1348      TCGA_04_1362   genesum  
  1:    A1BG          0.94565          0.70585  0.94565   
  2: A1BG-AS          0.97610          1.15850  0.97610   
  3:    A1CF          0.00000          0.02105  0.00000   
  4:   A2BP1          0.00300          0.04150  0.00300   
  5:   A2LD1          4.57975          5.02820  4.57975  
  6:     A2M         60.37320         36.09715 60.37320
```

and this is giving me the desired result

```
dt[, genesum:=apply(dt[,-1, with=FALSE],1, sum)]
head(dt)

       gene     TCGA_04_1348       TCGA_04_1362 genesum
  1:    A1BG          0.94565          0.70585  1.65150
  2: A1BG-AS          0.97610          1.15850  2.13460
  3:    A1CF          0.00000          0.02105  0.02105
  4:   A2BP1          0.00300          0.04150  0.04450
  5:   A2LD1          4.57975          5.02820  9.60795
  6:     A2M         60.37320         36.09715 96.47035
```

I have many more columns and rows, this is just a subset. Does this have anything to do with the way I set the key?

```
tables()
 NAME        NROW    MB COLS                                               KEY                                             
 [1,] dt     20,785  2  gene,TCGA_04_1348_01A,TCGA_04_1362_01A,genesum    gene
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few things:

1. `dt[, genesum:=lapply(.SD,sum), by=gene]` and `dt[, genesum:=apply(dt[ ,-1],1, sum)]` are quite different.

   - `dt[, genesum:=lapply(.SD,sum), by=gene]` loops over the **columns** of the `.SD` data.table and sums them
   - `dt[, genesum:=apply(dt[, -1], 1, sum)]` is looping over the rows (ie. `apply(x, 1, function)` applies `function` to every row in `x`
2. I think you can get what you want by calling `rowSums`, like so:

   ```
   dt[, genesum := rowSums(dt[, -1])]
   ```

Is that what you're after?

Comment: I see the difference now. Efficiency wise, there's no difference between apply and rowSums?

Comment: @sahir: I reckon `rowSums` should be faster as I believe it avoids the loop in R, however it will also create a copy of its input to convert it to a matrix if it isn't one already.

Comment: How can I write functions like rowSums...lets say rowMedian ?

Comment: @IndranilGayen: to avoid the looping in R you're going to have to write it in C/C++. Take a look at the [matrixStats](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/matrixStats)  package, it provides many such row* and col* operations, and they're made fast by delegating to C. (I've linked to github instead of CRAN so you can more easily browse tis source code)

Answer (score 2):

Here is one alternative ([based on this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37667335/row-operations-in-data-table-using-by-i)):

```
dt[ ,  genesum := sum(.SD[, -1, with=FALSE]), by = 1:NROW(dt) ]
```

another alternative:

```
# OR... you can create a column with row positions and apply your function by row
dt[, rowpos := .I]
dt[ ,  genesum := sum(.SD[, -1, with=FALSE]), by = rowpos]
```